# parameter type mismatch with pointer/reference

Tags: c++, c++11

I´m trying to add a player to a game I´m creating, but during this process I keep getting an error on the window parameter when I´m creating a new player in mainGame.cpp

The issue is a pointer/reference issue, but I can´t figure out how to fix it.

This is the error message:

> Parameter type mismatch: Incompatible types 'sf::RenderWindow &' and 'sf::RenderWindow *'

my mainGame.cpp look like this:

```
void mainGame::Initialize(sf::RenderWindow* window){
    this->player = new Player(20,100, config, window);
}

void mainGame::Destroy(sf::RenderWindow* window){
    delete this->player;
}
```

my mainGame.h file:

```
class mainGame : public tiny_state{
public:
    void Initialize(sf::RenderWindow* window);
    void Destroy(sf::RenderWindow* window);

protected:
    Player& player;
    Config config;
    sf::RenderWindow window;
};
```

my Plyer.cpp file:

```
Player::Player(float x, float y, const Config& config, sf::RenderWindow& )
    : x(x), y(y),
    config(config),
    window(window)
{
    rectangle.setSize(sf::Vector2f(sizeWidth, sizeHeight));
    rectangle.setFillColor(sf::Color::White);
}

void Player::move(float delta){
    if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Up))
        y -= speed * delta;
    if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Down))
        y += speed * delta;

    y = std::max(y, 0.f);
    y = std::min(y, (float)(config.screenheight - sizeHeight));
}

void Player::draw(){
    rectangle.setPosition(x, y);
    window.draw(rectangle);
}
```

my player.h file:

```
struct Player{
    Player(float x, float y, const Config& config, sf::RenderWindow& window);

    void move(float delta);
    void draw();

    const int sizeHeight = 100;
    const int sizeWidth = 10;
    const float speed = 5;
    float x, y;

    sf::RectangleShape rectangle;
    const Config& config;
    sf::RenderWindow& window;
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're passing a pointer where a reference is expected. Dereference it:

```
this->player = new Player(20,100, config, *window);
                                          ^
```

By the way, consider using smart pointers, like [`unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) to manage your memory. This way you'll be able to employ [rule of zero/three/five](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) instead of breaking of rule of three/five part of it.